# How to access Struct values in brownie

Tags: solidity, blockchain, python, brownie, debugging

```
//transaction struct of what a tx should have
struct Transaction{
    address to;
    uint value;
    bool executed;
    uint numConfirmations;
    mapping(address => bool) isConfirmed;
    mapping(address => bool) isRevoked;
}

//Array of transactions to keep track of each tx
Transaction[] public transactions;
```

A Transaction struct and an array type of Transaction. I want to access any Transaction value in the array and use it to for testing with brownie. How can I do this?

Will appreciate your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
# Get accoun
account = get_account()

# Deploy Contract
contract = ContractName.deploy(
    {"from": account}
)
# Retrieve the latest contract
contract = ContractName[-1]

print(contract.array_name(0))
```

Since `transactions` array is public, solidity automatically creates a `getter` function, which is the same name as your array. By making a call to this getter, you will get a tuple. For example: `contract.array_name(0)[0]` will print the first field of your struct.